# STL overload vector assignment

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

I'm working on a class that overloads the index operator ([]). To allow for assignment of an element, it's necessary for the operator to return a reference to the element. For example:

```
class myclass: public vector<int>
{
...
public:
    int & myclass::operator [] (int i)
    {
        return vector<int>::operator[](i);
    }
...
```

In this situation, the client code can use the returned reference to assign a value to an element. However, I would like to have a way to intercept the actual assignment of the element so I can use the assigned value to do some internal housekeeping. Is there a relatively clean and simple way to do this, or should I just create some accessor functions instead of using operator overloading?

Comment: One would ask why you're inheriting from `std::vector`.

Comment: Don't inherit from classes that do not provide a virtual destructor. At least not as long as you really know what you are doing!

Comment: I used std::vector to simplify the example a bit. My actual class uses a map. What I'm trying to implement is a two-way mapping. I need an efficient way to get the key using only the value as a lookup, without resorting to a linear search. I plan use another vector/map to maintain a reverse mapping but I'm unable to capture the assigned value.

At this point it seems that it would be better to just use a getter/setter than to define a new class just to capture the assignment. Another issue with wrapping the value in a class would be that it would capture the value but not the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the std::vector index operator already returns reference to the item (either const or non-const), so no need to inherit and override.

If you want to intercept the assignment of the value, the correct way of doing this is to define/override the assignment operator of the value itself (you cannot do it in the vector index operator). That will of course not work with pure int, so you'd need to wrap the int in a class which will provide the assignment operator and there you can do "anything you want".

**EDIT:**

Ok I see, so then it might be needed to do some overrides. For the reverse lookup, one of the possibilities could be to not store the value in the reverse structure, but a pointer to it (to the original location). The value assignment in the original structure would then be reflected with the pointer redirection. This would also need to pass a custom comparison operator to the reverse lookup map, to not compare the pointers, but the values.

In general, it might be worth to also check [boost::multi_index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html), which allows to do exactly that - create a single structure with multiple lookup indices.

Comment: For clarification, the "housekeeping" I need to do is to keep an auxiliary data structure that I can use to do a reverse lookup, i.e. to efficiently retrieve the index from the value without resorting to a linear search. 

Wrapping the value assignment in a class in will give me access to the value but not to the key, so that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to intercept the assignment of an integer. However, you could instead return a reference to a custom type whose assignment operator you have overloaded. The custom type can be convertible to int, so that it can be used as one.

Of course, this means that you cannot inherit `std::vector<int>` which returns a reference to `int`. You should avoid inheriting `std::vector` publicly anyway. A user of your class may accidentally delete the object through a `std::vector<int>*` which would have undefined behaviour.